# Mathematica's NDSolve and SciPy's solve_ivp returning different results

Tags: python, scipy, wolfram-mathematica, ode

This question involves both Python and Mathematica code.

I want to solve a system of complex ODEs numerically. Originally, I used NDSolve, but since I ended up needing to do an extensive parameter search, I decided to switch to using Python, specifically SciPy's solve_ivp function. However, I quickly ran into the following problem:

A, B, C, and D are the four coupled complex ODEs I want to solve for. Notably, abs(A)^2 + abs(B)^2 + abs(C)^2 + abs(D)^2 = 1 always holds (due to the nature of the problem). Indeed, this is always true in NDSolve's solution

[image: ndsolve result].

However, when I transferred the code to Python, the result using solve_ivp is incorrect.

[image: solve_ivp result]

At first, I was sure that there was a typo when I transferred the code to Mathematica. However, I've spent a couple of days looking over the functions, and haven't found anything. I also had a friend familiar with both languages look it over, and they did not find anything either (but that was a slightly different version of the code then the one presented here, which I simplified to make more readable).

Therefore, my question is if there is something in the definition of either NDSolve or solve_ivp that might cause this difference, or if there is a way to reproduce Mathematica's result in using Python.

Mathematica Code:

```
r[t_, c_, b_] := Sqrt[(c*t)^2 + b^2]
Sol[t0_, tf_, C1_, C2_, a_, c_, b_, d_, \[Phi]1_, \[Phi]2_] := 
 Module[{g}, g = C1*C2 ; 
  NDSolve[{A'[
      t] == -I (A[
          t]*(C1*a/2 + C2*a*UnitStep[d - r[t, c, b]]/2 + 
           g/r[t, c, b]^3) - 
        3*g/r[t, c, b]^5*C11[t]*((c*t)^2 - b^2 - 2*I*c*t*b)), 
    A[t0] == Cos[\[Phi]1]/Sqrt[2],
    
    B'[t] == -I*(D1[
          t]*(2*g/r[t, c, b]^3 - 3*g/r[t, c, b]^5*((c*t)^2 + b^2)) + 
        B[t]*(-g/r[t, c, b]^3 + C1*a/2 - 
           C2*a*UnitStep[d - r[t, c, b]]/2)), 
    B[t0] == Sin[\[Phi]1]/Sqrt[2], 
    C11'[t] ==
     -I*(C11[
          t]*(-C1*a/2 - C2*a*UnitStep[d - r[t, c, b]]/2 + 
           g/r[t, c, b]^3) - 
        3*g/r[t, c, b]^5*A[t]*((c*t)^2 - b^2 + 2*I*c*t*b)), 
    C11[t0] == Sin[\[Phi]1]*E^(-I*\[Phi]2)/Sqrt[2], D1'[t] ==
     
     -I*(B[t]*(2*g/r[t, c, b]^3 - 3*g/r[t, c, b]^5*((c*t)^2 + b^2)) + 
        D1[t]*(-g/r[t, c, b]^3 - C1*a/2 + 
           C2*a*UnitStep[d - r[t, c, b]]/2)), 
    D1[t0] == Cos[\[Phi]1]*E^(-I*\[Phi]2)/Sqrt[2]}, {A, B, C11, 
    D1}, {t, t0, tf}]]
```

To reproduce result:

```
S = Sol[-100, 100, 1, 1.25, 100, 1, 1, 10, 0, 0];
Rasterize[
 Plot[{Abs[A[t]]^2 /. S, Abs[B[t]]^2 /. S, Abs[C11[t]]^2 /. S, 
   Abs[D1[t]]^2 /. S, 
   Abs[A[t]]^2 + Abs[B[t]]^2 + Abs[C11[t]]^2 + Abs[D1[t]]^2 /. 
    S}, {t, -100, 100}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"A^2", "B^2", "C^2", "D^2", "Sum=1"}, 
  PlotLabel -> "Working Version with Mathematica NDSolve"]]
```

Python Code:

```
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def r(t, c, b):
    return np.sqrt((c*t)**2 + b**2)


def coeff(t, z, k):
    C1, C2, a, c, b, d = k
    g = C1*C2

    A, B, C, D = z

    dAdt = -1j * (A * (C1*a/2 + C2*a*np.heaviside(d-r(t,c,b), 1)/2 +
    g/r(t,c,b)**3) - 3*g/r(t,c,b)**5 * C * ((c * t)**2 - b**2 - 2*1j*c*t*b))

    dBdt = -1j*(D*(2*g/r(t,c,b)**3 - 3*g/r(t,c,b)**5*((c*t)**2 + b**2)) + B *(-g/r(t,c,b)**3 + C1*a/2 - C2*a*np.heaviside(d-r(t,c,b), 1)/2))

    dCdt = -1j * (C*(-C1*a/2 - C2*a*np.heaviside(d-r(t,c,b), 1)/2 +
    g/r(t,c,b)**3) - 3*g/r(t,c,b)**5*A*((c*t)**2 - b**2 + 2*1j*c*t*b))

    dDdt = -1j*(B*(2*g/r(t,c,b)**3- 3*g/r(t,c,b)**5*((c*t)**2 + b**2)) + D *(-g/r(t,c,b)**3 - C1*a/2 + C2*a*np.heaviside(d-r(t,c,b), 1)/2))

    return [dAdt, dBdt, dCdt, dDdt]

def solver(t0, tf, k, phi1, phi2):

    a0 = np.cos(phi1)/np.sqrt(2)

    b0 = np.sin(phi1)/np.sqrt(2)


    c0 = (np.sin(phi1)/np.sqrt(2))*np.exp(-1j*phi2)

    d0 = (np.cos(phi1)/np.sqrt(2))*np.exp(-1j*phi2)

    z0 = (a0, b0, c0, d0)

    return solve_ivp(coeff, [t0, tf], z0, args=(k,))
```

To reproduce result:

```
k = [1, 1.25, 100, 1, 1, 10]
sol=solver(-100, 100, k, 0, 0)

plt.plot(sol.t, np.abs(sol.y[0])**2, label="A^2")
plt.plot(sol.t, np.abs(sol.y[1])**2, label="B^2")
plt.plot(sol.t, np.abs(sol.y[2])**2, label = "C^2")
plt.plot(sol.t, np.abs(sol.y[3])**2, label="D^2")
plt.plot(sol.t, np.abs(sol.y[0])**2+np.abs(sol.y[1])**2+np.abs(sol.y[2])**2+np.abs(sol.y[3])**2, label="Sum != 1???")
plt.legend()
plt.title("Not Working solve_ivp Version")
plt.show()
```

#### Edit:

I tried splitting the ODE so that I could remove the discontinuity due to the Heaviside Function. It definitely made things better, but not by much:[image: Result from new code, as given below.]What I think is most interesting is the shift at t=0, as that is not a discontinuity. Even before that point, the function is shifting away from Sum=1, as it did before.

New Code:

```
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def r(t, c, b):
    return np.sqrt((c*t)**2 + b**2)


def coeff(t, z, k):
    C1, C2, a, c, b, d = k
    g = C1*C2

    A, B, C, D = z

    dAdt = -1j * (A * (C1*a/2 + C2*a/2 +
    g/r(t,c,b)**3) - 3*g/r(t,c,b)**5 * C * ((c * t)**2 - b**2 - 2*1j*c*t*b))

    dBdt = -1j*(D*(2*g/r(t,c,b)**3 - 3*g/r(t,c,b)**5*((c*t)**2 + b**2)) + B *(-g/r(t,c,b)**3 + C1*a/2 - C2*a/2))

    dCdt = -1j * (C*(-C1*a/2 - C2*a/2 +
    g/r(t,c,b)**3) - 3*g/r(t,c,b)**5*A*((c*t)**2 - b**2 + 2*1j*c*t*b))

    dDdt = -1j*(B*(2*g/r(t,c,b)**3- 3*g/r(t,c,b)**5*((c*t)**2 + b**2)) + D *(-g/r(t,c,b)**3 - C1*a/2 + C2*a))

    return [dAdt, dBdt, dCdt, dDdt]

def coeff2(t, z, k):
    C1, C2, a, c, b, d = k
    g = C1*C2

    A, B, C, D = z

    dAdt = -1j * (A * (C1*a/2 +
    g/r(t,c,b)**3) - 3*g/r(t,c,b)**5 * C * ((c * t)**2 - b**2 - 2*1j*c*t*b))

    dBdt = -1j*(D*(2*g/r(t,c,b)**3 - 3*g/r(t,c,b)**5*((c*t)**2 + b**2)) + B *(-g/r(t,c,b)**3 + C1*a/2))

    dCdt = -1j * (C*(-C1*a/2 +
    g/r(t,c,b)**3) - 3*g/r(t,c,b)**5*A*((c*t)**2 - b**2 + 2*1j*c*t*b))

    dDdt = -1j*(B*(2*g/r(t,c,b)**3- 3*g/r(t,c,b)**5*((c*t)**2 + b**2)) + D *(-g/r(t,c,b)**3 - C1*a/2))

    return [dAdt, dBdt, dCdt, dDdt]

def solver(t0, tf, k, phi1, phi2, order=1):

    a0 = np.cos(phi1)/np.sqrt(2)

    b0 = np.sin(phi1)/np.sqrt(2)


    c0 = (np.sin(phi1)/np.sqrt(2))*np.exp(-1j*phi2)

    d0 = (np.cos(phi1)/np.sqrt(2))*np.exp(-1j*phi2)

    z0 = (a0, b0, c0, d0)
    if order == 2 :

        return solve_ivp(coeff, [t0, tf], z0, args=(k,))
    else:
        return solve_ivp(coeff2, [t0, tf], z0, args=(k,))


k = [1, 1.25, 100, 1, 1, 10]

t0=-100
tf=100

t1 = -np.sqrt(k[-1]**2 - k[-2]**2)/k[-4] - 0.00000001
t2 = np.sqrt(k[-1]**2 - k[-2]**2)/k[-4] + 0.000000001

sol1 = solver(t0, t1, k, 0, 0)
sol2 = solve_ivp(coeff, [t1,t2], [sol1.y[0][-1], sol1.y[1][-1], sol1.y[2][-1], sol1.y[3][-1]], args=(k,))
sol3 = solve_ivp(coeff2, [t2,tf], [sol2.y[0][-1], sol2.y[1][-1], sol2.y[2][-1], sol2.y[3][-1]], args=(k,))

t = np.concatenate((sol1.t,sol2.t, sol3.t), axis=None)
A = np.concatenate((sol1.y[0],sol2.y[0],sol3.y[0]), axis=None)
B = np.concatenate((sol1.y[1],sol2.y[1],sol3.y[1]), axis=None)
C = np.concatenate((sol1.y[2],sol2.y[2],sol3.y[2]), axis=None)
D = np.concatenate((sol1.y[3],sol2.y[3],sol3.y[3]), axis=None)


plt.plot(t, np.abs(A)**2, label="A^2")
plt.plot(t, np.abs(B)**2, label="B^2")
plt.plot(t, np.abs(C)**2, label = "C^2")
plt.plot(t, np.abs(D)**2, label="D^2")
plt.plot(t, np.abs(A)**2+np.abs(B)**2+np.abs(C)**2+np.abs(D)**2, label="Sum != 1???")
plt.legend()
plt.title("Not Working solve_ivp Version")
print(np.max(np.abs(A)**2+np.abs(B)**2+np.abs(C)**2+np.abs(D)**2))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica is smart enough to figure out what type of solver is most accurate in most cases; with `scipy.integrate.solve_ivp` you have to [specify the `method` parameter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html) if the default is not good enough. Unfortunately, not all solvers for `solve_ivp` work well with complex-valued problems and the other solvers that support complex values behave much worse for your ODE than the default (`RK45`).

You can find out [what solver Mathematica is using under the hood](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/150).

Your derivatives include `np.heaviside` functions, which are discontinuous; this is something that ODE solvers generally don't like; for example RK45 is designed for functions that can be approximated locally by a functions with continuous 4th-order derivatives. Consider figuring out where the jumps in the derivatives are and integrating in segments between them. For example, if you want to solve over the range t=0..1 and the discontinuities are at t=a and t=b; then integrate from 0 to a-1e-9, then from a+1e-9 to b-1e-9, then from b+1e-9 to 1. The plot of the bad solution suggests that there are problems in the derivatives at a few discrete points.

EDIT: upon closer inspection, the factors `1/r(t,c,b)**3` and `**5` are sharply peaked at `t=0` (increasing by several orders of magnitude); it could be that the ODE becomes 'stiff' there. (Innocuous ODEs like *d(A, B)/dt = (-aB, -bA)* with positive *a, b* tend to be stiff). Splitting the variables into real and imaginary parts so that you can use a solver suitable for real-valued stiff equations may be worth a try.

Comment: Hm, would you recommend a different solver if I recast the problem as 8 real ODEs instead of four complex ones? I can definitely do that and use your suggestion for dealing with the discontinuity. I also followed your link, but unlike the examples given there, the results of Trace[] does not show anything more than "Automatic." Thanks!

Comment: I tried to remove the discontinuity as you suggested, and while the plot looks better, the answer is still incorrect (see edited post). I'll try recasting it as a set of real ODEs I suppose.